# how do I add -std=c++11 to the compiler options in my NetBeans IDE?

Tags: c++, c++11, netbeans

Netbeans give me the following error:

"error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must
be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.

Im not sure how to fix this. any help?

Comment: Have you tried googling? [Second hit for "netbeans c++ compiler options"](https://forums.netbeans.org/ntopic18439.html).

Comment: yes, but I am still not exactly sure how to fix this.

Comment: @Runee What's unclear about the solution in the link?

Comment: Nothing now. I found out how to do it. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

First: Open project properties and then Code Assistance->C++ Compiler. In C++ Standard select C++11.

Second: you must enable C++11 in your project. If you created the c++ project from inside Netbeans, in project properties->Build->C++ Compiler, you must set C++ standard to C++11, and then click on dots in Additional Options and ensure that the -std=c++11 option is enabled.

If you imported the project with external makefile, you must add manually this option in the makefile.

Comment: Where do I add other compiler options if any such as optimization, warnings etc?

Comment: In the same place

Comment: OK got it now. I was looking at Tools-> Options-> C/C++ and not in project properties.